# What entity is causing the exception in entity framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm doing something like that in my code

```
var item = myContext.Entity1
             .Include(e => e.Entity2)
             ....
             .Include(e => e.Entity19)
             .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == 1)
```

Now i'm getting an `EntityCommandExecutionException` with the inner Exception error `Invalid column name 'Id'.`

I was wondering if there's a way to see what Entity has caused this Exception?
What I did so far, is to comment out/ comment in the Includes till i isolated the promematic one.

Is there an easier way?

Comment: Instead of chaining your expected output using dot notation, put them on separate lines. And chain only one thing at a time. Then you'll see the clause that's causing your issue.

Comment: As @ManoDestra suggested, but in addition you could use `ToList()` on every statement (only for debug issues) to force Linq to apply the filter in the specific LOC.

Comment: are you guys saying that the information what entity is causing the problem is not stored anywhere in the exeption (or somewhere else)?

Comment: what in `InnerException` and `Data` of your `EntityCommandExecutionException` ?

Comment: It's System.Collections.ListDictonaryInternal with a Count of 6 items. But when I expand everything in the Detail no useful information is showed. @tschmit007

Comment: If you can view the SQL, copy and paste it into SQL Management Studio and you will get a more specific error line and column.